# How to split ESRI file geodatabase into two or three by region?

Tags: arcgis-desktop, file-geodatabase, spatial-database

I have got a ESRI file geodatabase(10.3) with many feature-classes(Polygon, Polyline & point). I don't have enterprise ESRI license. I have to split the entire data into two unique parts to do **simultaneous** edit/update by two employees.

How can I split the file geodatabse(all feature-classes) into two portions, each containing all the feature classes as shown in the image?
[image]

Comment: Your question as it is now is somewhat vague.  Could you please edit it to include how you want to split the geodatabase? For example, do you want to split it so that one person can edit features that another person is also editing?  Or do you want one person to edit points, another to edit lines, and third person to edit polygons?  Also, you say ArcGIS geodatabase.  But there are several types of geodatabases.  Is it an ESRI File Geodatabase?  Or a personal geodatabase? Or an SDE Geodatabase? What have you tried so far?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I'm assuming you are trying to do this split spatially so one employee can work on a half while the other employee works on the other half. I would use model builder. Define the two areas you want to split the database into with polygons. Use each polygon to clip each feature class in the database and set the export to a new database. Do that for each half.

Comment: Yes, you are right. Is model builder a must?

Comment: Well if you want the process automated you would either have to use model builder or python. If you're not well-versed in python it will be much faster to do it in model builder. It's pretty easy to get the hang of. Otherwise you would have to manually clip your features (which isn't a big deal if you don't have many feature classes).

Comment: I have 9 feature classes in my geodatabase.

Comment: Why not just clip it manually then? Just use a shapefile to define your clip areas and export into each database. It'll take less than 30 minutes.

Comment: Can the Target Workspace be a same file-geodatabase for all layers? When I split layer1, layer2 & layer3 to single target file-geodatabase, only layer3 (last one) was seen inside the file-gepdatabase.